# Function to replace outliers in Python

Tags: python

I need to create a FUNCTION to replace outliers in  columns of my dataset with Mean+/- 3* StandardDeviation of that column

For example, The outliers are identified if the value is greater/less than Mean+/- 3* StandardDeviation.

So, If the value in A lets say 285 is an outlier on the upper side it needs to be replaced by Mean+ 3* StandardDeviation. If the outlier is on the lower side it needs to be replaced with Mean - 3* StandardDeviation.

This needs to be done with all columns.

A    B    C

195 106 70

250 121 81

245 127 80

225 150 95

285 130 84

228 180 110

205 138 71

Comment: Take a look at [numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

Comment: Ideally, you should only use standard deviation when the data is guassian distributed. If In case your data is not normally distributed, then standard deviation may not work to find outliers. user Interquartile Rule to find outliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the help of the `map` method which internally gets called by each element of each row and further checks whether val is an outlier or not. Code for this can be something like written below.

```
def replace_outlier(val, mean, std):
    if val > mean + 3*std:
        return mean + 3*std 
    elif val < mean - 3*std:
        return mean - 3*std
    return val

for col in df.columns:
    mean = df[col].mean()
    std_dev = df[col].std(axis=0)
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: replace_outlier(x, mean, std_dev))
```

Comment: how can the function be used for all the columns in the data frame?

Comment: I am running a for-loop across all the columns present in the data frame. For each column in dataframe it will run `replace_outlier(...) ` method.